# Passing Optional Arguments in a redefined command

Tags: macros

I am designing something in which getting all of my actual images together is much more time consuming than the writing part, and so I am using a wrapper command on `\includegraphics` to replace the image with a test square unless the specified file exists, so I can check the other formatting as I go.

```
\newcommand{\includegraphicsmaybe}[1]{\IfFileExists{../Images/#1}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{#1}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{test.jpg}}}
```

However, I don't know how to pass in any more formatting arguments to the actual `\includegraphics` command, such as to rotate this one (as opposed to all of them), or whatever the case may be. How can I do this?

Comment: Just define a command with optional argument and the empty argument as default (see [`usrguide-historic`](https://texdoc.org/serve/usrguide-historic/0) section 3.4 or [`usrguide`](https://texdoc.org/serve/usrguide/0) section 2) and append it with `,#1` to the optional argument of `\includegraphics`).

Comment: BTW: It would help, if you'd show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). For example, the `\includegraphics` of package `graphicx` does not support option `valign`.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the order in which the keywords are processed seems to matter, and `width=\linewidth` before `rotate` is not a good idea.  OTOH, you can enter the `width` twice and the second one wins.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\newcommand{\includegraphicsmaybe}[2][]{% #1 = optional keys, #2 = filename
  \IfFileExists{#2}%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1,valign=t]{#2}}%
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1,valign=t]{example-image-duck}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\includegraphicsmaybe[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}\hfill
\includegraphicsmaybe[rotate=90, width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphicsmaybe{test.jpg}
\end{document}
```